# How to create a column B that dynamically calculates SHA1 of column A when column A got inserted?

Tags: mysql, sql

This question continue to the previous question
[How to create Trigger to prevent inserting the duplicate row in MYSQL 5.0.27?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986670/how-to-create-trigger-to-prevent-inserting-the-duplicate-row-in-mysql-5-0-27)

Now I have a I have a table MyText which have ID (Auto incrementation ) column, text (varchar 700, utf8) column

```
Id - text
1  - this is my text
2  - xxxx
```

Now I want to add a new column "`textHash`" which is `SHA1(lower(text))`. That means everytime  there is a new text inserted into `text` column, then the "`textHash`" column will calculate the hash value & updated accordingly.

Ex, at the beginning

```
Id - text            - textHash
1  - this is my text - 5sd4as55ads
2  - xxxx            - zxcz5454
```

Then if someone `insert into myTable (text) values ('new text')`, then the table will be like this:

```
Id - text            - textHash
1  - this is my text - 5sd4as55ads
2  - xxxx            - zxcz5454
3  - new text        - 212121zxc
```

SO how to deal with it?

Comment: Triggers is what you want. Alternatively, you could consider using computed columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following for the trigger:

```
delimiter //
create trigger texthash
before insert on mytext
for each row
begin
   set new.txt_hash = sha1(lower(new.text));
end;
//
delimiter ;
```

**Fiddle** example is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67b15/1/0

You have to set the delimitter to something other than a semicolon (in my example, // ) to differentiate between the start and end of the trigger, as there is a semicolon within the statement. (You can set it back to a semicolon immediately after the trigger is created)

Note that the SHA1 value is always 40 characters regardless of the length of the text field. Ie. the SHA1 hash of 'new text' is 1eb8a29393c0e376645481c0185ec8ef05c0b65c

Regarding your comment, try formatting what you posted exactly as follows (line by line): Only thing I noticed is you forgot a semicolon after the SET

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER textHash_InsertTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
begin
   set new.textHash=sha1(lower(new.text));
end;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: u forgot sha1(lower(new.text))? since I don't care about case

Comment: it said the "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set new.textHash=sha1(lower(new.text)) end' at line 1"

Comment: DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER textHash_InsertTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON myTable FOR EACH ROW begin set new.textHash=sha1(lower(new.text)) end; $$ DELIMITER;

Comment: @Tum probably just the semicolon after your SET (it's not there), but try using what I just put into my answer above to clarify anything else

Answer (score 0):

```
create trigger hashing before insert on table
for each row begin
   set table.textHash= md5(text);
end;
```

Not too sure about the syntax but the logic should be correct.